# SOLVED - Bug with DOMPDF

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with the library DOMPDF to export a page of magento to PDF.

I have multiple websites but only in two websites i can't export a quotation with products.

I have the next error:

[image: Error frame]

Any idea?

My table HTML:

```
<table class="items-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Όνομα</th>
            <th>Περιγραφή</th>
            <th class="qty">Ποσ</th>
            <th class="price">Τιμή</th>
            <th class="total">Σύνολο</th>
            <th class="show">Εμφάνιση</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="quotation_lines">
            <tr id="quotation_line_template" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="*" objcontrol="row" style="display:none;">
                <td objentity="quotation_line" objfield="sku">
                    <input>
                    <div class="results"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="title"></a>
                </td>
                <td objentity="quotation_line" objfield="name"></td>
                <td objentity="quotation_line" objfield="description"><input></td>
                <td class="qty" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="qty"><input type="number" min="0" max="999" step="1"></td>
                <td class="price" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="price"></td>
                <td class="total" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="total"></td>
                <td class="show"><input type="checkbox" value="" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="show"></td>
                <td class="actions" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="line_id" objcontrol="actions">
                    <a href="#" class="action action-remove" title="Αφαίρεση"><i class="ion ion-close">&nbsp;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr id="quotation-line-1" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="*" objcontrol="row" style="display: table-row;">
                <td objentity="quotation_line" objfield="sku">
                    <input style="display: none;">
                    <div class="results" style="top: 53px; display: none;"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="title" target="_blank" style="display: inline;">FTXB35C</a>
                </td>
                <td objentity="quotation_line" objfield="name"><span>FTXB35C SPLIT<no comp<h="" p<="" span=""></no></span></td>
                <td objentity="quotation_line" objfield="description"><input></td>
                <td class="qty" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="qty"><input type="number" min="0" max="999" step="1"></td>
                <td class="price" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="price"><span class="price">1.425,00&nbsp;€</span></td>
                <td class="total" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="total"><span class="price">1.425,00&nbsp;€</span></td>
                <td class="show"><input type="checkbox" value="" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="show"></td>
                <td class="actions" objentity="quotation_line" objfield="line_id" objcontrol="actions">
                    <a href="#" class="action action-remove" title="Αφαίρεση" id=""><i class="ion ion-close">&nbsp;</i></a>
                </td>
            </tr></tbody>

        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6" class="title">Total (excl. VAT)</th>
            <th class="value" objentity="quotation" objfield="base">1.425,00&nbsp;€</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6" class="title">VAT %</th>
            <th class="value">
                <input type="text" id="quotation_tax_percent" objentity="quotation" objfield="tax_percent">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6" class="title">VAT amount</th>
            <th class="value" objentity="quotation" objfield="taxes_total">0,00&nbsp;€</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6" class="title">Total (incl. VAT)</th>
            <th class="value" objentity="quotation" objfield="total">1.425,00&nbsp;€</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

This website is Greece, for example, with more products in France i haven't this bug.

Thanks

**SOLVED**
I have a problem with a product name because is like this "Test

Comment: Seems like invalid HTML can cause it; https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/657

Comment: Ricky Odin Matthews i add my HTML table.

Comment: RE: Your solution, if you use an escape function in PHP you'll avoid that issue also and not have to rename product. Thanks

Comment: if you solved it, you should post this as an answer and accept it to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I had a problem with the name of a product, this product contains special characters then when render the HTML I had the problem.